# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session 2.2.0 is Deprecated, what is the replacement for a .Net Core 7 MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-core, deprecated

Please, would anyone know :

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session 2.2.0 is Deprecated, what is the replacement for a .Net Core 7 MVC project ?

Thank You.

No reference for a replacement in .Nuget and could not find an answer on the web

Comment: I don't know about a replacement, but does [the information here](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/217) possibly help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I check the Package in nuget, and [find the source code of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session`](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/tree/774079d60d29762ef7c8bba3f0fa06e73cb323f2). I aslo find the info about this moved to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore.

This means that in the new asp.net core 7 project, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session package` was required to be installed before. Now it is a `built-in` feature and no longer needs to be installed like the previous package.

[image]

[image]